# Golf Define "Rolling Draw"

Tags: meaning

In the context of golf, what does "rolling draw" mean?

I do not having an example sentence unfortunately, but other words in the same context include Walker Cup, Forecaddies, Niblick, Fairway bunkers, and Greens.

I've tried both Google and Wikipedia without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *draw* in golf is a shot that moves in the direction of the golfer (as opposed to a *fade*, which moves away from the golfer). For example, in a right-handed golfer, a draw will curve to the golfer's left as he looks down the fairway, while a fade will curve to the right (both deviating from a straight, or linear, trajectory). This also puts some backspin on the ball, which causes it to stop shorter than a fade, which has forward spin. A *rolling draw* describes a shot with draw that "releases" on impact and rolls forward farther than a normal draw.

> **draw**
>   5 *Golf* hit (the ball) so that it travels slightly to the left (for a left-handed player, the right), usually as a result of spin given to the ball: *he had to learn to draw the ball—not least for the tee shots at Augusta.*
>   • *Billiards* impart backspin to (the cue ball), making it move backwards after hitting an object ball. [NOAD]

It is useful to note the meaning in billiards, since they derive from the same idea, of putting backspin on a ball.